# Conditionally Ignore files in gulp.src

Tags: angularjs, gulp, glob, gulp-filter, node-glob

The source code is used for 2 projects, Each project has some common code. 
I want to conditionally ignore a module/folder/directory via gulp task.

When I do following it works perfectly

```
return gulp.src(
  config.appMarkupFiles
  '!app/settings', '!app/settings/**'
)
```

However, I want to do it conditionally. 
I have also tried the following code using gulp-filter which does not work for me.

```
var isQA = $.yargs.argv.stage === 'qa';

var filterSettings = $.filter(['!app/settings{, /**}'])
return gulp.src(
  config.appMarkupFiles
)
.pipe(($.if(isQA,$.filter(filterSettings)))
```

[image: folder structure for reference only.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gulpfile is just JavaScript so you can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to conditionally exclude files in  `gulp.src()`:

```
var isQA = $.yargs.argv.stage === 'qa';

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src([config.appMarkupFiles].concat((isQA) ? ['!app/settings{,/**}'] : []))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Using `gulp-filter` works, but you had two mistakes in your code:

1. There's an unnecessary space in `!app/settings{, /**}` and
2. You're applying `$.filter` twice.

Here's a working solution using `gulp-filter`:

```
var isQA = $.yargs.argv.stage === 'qa';

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.appMarkupFiles)
    .pipe($.if(isQA, $.filter(['!app/settings{,/**}'])))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working. I tried both the option you suggested alternatively. With No luck yet.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific if you want me to help you.

Comment: It is not ignoring all the markup files. not just the from settings folder. If I comment it then all markup files get processed to www.

Comment: That's not really helpful. Edit your question to give an exact description of your problem (current code, existing directory structure, expected result, actual result). See [mcve]